# Datetime value with different culture not formatting correctly

Tags: c#, datetime, localization, cultureinfo

I'm having a slight issue with Thread culture and getting a date to display properly.
I am overloading the ToString() method of the DateTime class.

With culture "en-CA", my date is coming out in the right format "yyyy/MM/dd"
but with culture "fr-CA", my date is coming out "yyyy-MM-dd"

I've made some unit test to display the issue.
The english test works but the french always fails.

Even if I change the GetDateInStringMethod to do .ToShortDateString.  I still get the same issue.

```
[Test()]
public void ValidInEnglish()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = Utility.DatePattern;
    DateTime? currentDate = new DateTime(2009,02,7);
    string expected = "2009/02/07";
    string actual = DateUtils.GetDateInString(currentDate);

//This works
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[Test()]
public void ValidInFrench()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = Utility.DatePattern;
    DateTime? currentDate = new DateTime(2009, 02, 7);
    string expected = "2009/02/07";
    string actual = DateUtils.GetDateInString(currentDate);
// This doesn't work
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

public static string GetDateInString(DateTime? obj)
{
    if (obj == null || !obj.HasValue)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    return obj.Value.ToString(Utility.DatePattern);
}

public const string DatePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't work because using french culture defaults the datetime formatter to use `-` instead of `/` as a separator character. 
If you want to keep your date the same no matter the culture then use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` 
if you want to use the french formatting the change your expected test result to `"2009-02-07"`. 
If you are looking for more info check [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx).
And if you want a personal recommendation for a lib to use for dealing with the awesomeness that is Globalization then I'd recommend [Noda Time](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Change this line:

```
return obj.Value.ToString(Utility.DatePattern);
```

to this:

```
return obj.Value.ToString(Utility.DatePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Read about it here: [System.Globalization.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe I forgot about that >_<